# How do the Hat Dash points work?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, winter-bash-2020, hat-dash

I know this seems like a simple question - I had just assumed that your points were directly related to the amount of time spent in the game. But my top scores table definitely shows situations where the number of seconds I played was less, but I got a higher score. Is there something else that gives bonuses or affects your speed as you play, or is this a bug? I watched to see if jumping over something added a bonus or slowed down the movement speed, but I didn't notice any obvious changes.

Here's some examples from my top scores list, and why it confused me. Compare rows 1 and 2, where 1 has 161 more points, but 2 lasts 0.36 seconds longer. Rows 3-5 have some similar things happening, but on a much smaller scale. That's small enough I can believe it's timing variability in the code, but the difference between 1 and 2 is far larger than that.

| # | Score | Seconds |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 620 | 39.07 |
| 2 | 459 | 39.43 |
| 3 | 57 | 4.89 |
| 4 | 55 | 4.99 |
| 5 | 52 | 4.39 |

Comment: Maybe connection blips.. if the score is calculated server side, the code sending the data to the server might delay sometimes due to slow connection, probably.

Comment: My understanding is that the speed impacts your score... and we randomize the starting speed, so you can have different scores for the same time spent.

Comment: I was hoping this would be on hoofprint count.

Comment: @Catija I hadn't noticed that the start speed changed too. If the points are based on distance rather than time, then that sounds like a likely explanation!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The start speed, accelaration, and max speed are all very slightly randomized per game, such that each game will feel very similar, but will never be exactly the same.

As the score is calculated based on the current speed, this means that you will almost always have slightly different scoring velocities.

> that's strange, my speed changed
> ok, it's really by design
> that is how points work